# How to get a list of days using Python's QuantLib

Tags: python, date, quantlib

Given a calendar, I wanted to get a list of first 2 business days (week starts from Sunday) of the week prior to 4 weeks to the week of a given date.

Is there any way to get the list of such days? I am using `QuantLib` module in `Python`.

Below is my implementation so far -

```
import QuantLib as ql
import pandas as pd

date = ql.Date(2, 7, 2020)
date_prev = date - ql.Period(4, ql.Weeks)
us_calendar = ql.UnitedStates()

print(date)
print(date_prev)
```

As you see, above code is just blindly deducting 4 weeks from `date`, without consideration from `us_calendar`, nor providing the list of first 2 days on that week which I was looking for

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Comment: Perhaps a sample I/O along with what you've tried would be helpful.

Comment: @DirtyBit , just added my codes which I tried. Not sure though if I am going towards the right direction

Answer (score 1):

I'm more than 2 years late in answering, but just in case it's still useful, I'd do something like this:

```
date = ql.Date(2, 7, 2020)

# 4 weeks before:
d = date - ql.Period(4, ql.Weeks)

# if needed, go back to the Sunday of that week:
while d.weekday() != ql.Sunday:
    d = d - 1

# now get the first two business days:
d1 = us_calendar.advance(d, 1, ql.Days)
d2 = us_calendar.advance(d1, 1, ql.Days)

print([d1, d2])
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
import QuantLib as ql
calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
start = ql.Date(7,5,2020)
previous = calendar.advance(start, -4, ql.Weeks)
days = [calendar.advance(previous, n, ql.Days) for n in [1,2]]
print(days)
```

[Date(10,4,2020), Date(13,4,2020)]

Comment: Thanks. While this is near to correct, we are just adding 2 days to the 'previous'. Whilst I wanted to have begging 2 business days for the week of 'previous'